# Does Response.Expires = 0 Kill the Current Session?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

The question is pretty much in the title. I have an application where my session randomly dies (even though it's set to expire in 25 minutes).

Could me having `Response.Expires=0` at the top of the page have something to do with this?

Comment: This can happen for example if the client machine change IP, or if the connection is being reset i.e. network problems. Usually it's nothing to do with the code itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525906). `Response.Expires` affects how a page is cached on the client. It does not affect the session.